# Using Service stub during Activity Junit test

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am writing a Junit test for activity which launching a service:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyClass.class));
```

For the purpose of the test, I want to replace `MyClass.class` with a stub class *(MyStubClass.class)*

I did an extensive search on SOF but was unable to find a solution.
Is it possible to make the swap without adding test related code to the application?

Comment: Have you tried JMockIt or Mockito?  I've used both with great success for this sort of thing.

Comment: I read here: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html that mock and stub are not really the same. As far as i understood, mock won't give me the result that i want. Can you please point me to a specific example in which JMockIt or Mockito swap classes during unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

Commenting on the above thread, while I agree with much of what that article says, I'm not sure I agree with all of it, or even the need to make such a fine-grain distinction.  In my mind I think of mocks as run-time replacements and stubs as unfinished work or test-specific implementations that rely on polymorphism rather actual replacement.  But, I'm no expert so take my opinion with a grain of salt.  In any case, when you replace a class with a mocked version, theres no requirement to do anything fancy in your mock implementation.

Anyway, here's the documentation you asked for: http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/StateBasedTesting.html#mocks

I've used jmockit to stub interfaces I that I didnt care about implementing, replace Android stub implementations with stubs that dont throw exceptions, and on occasion to replace those same stubs with minimally functional implementations.  In my case I wanted to be able to run my unit tests quickly, which meant running them outside of an Emulator or physical device.  If you are interested in doing that kind of thing, using a mocking package in tandem with something like Robolectric is a life saver.